# Combining two clips (feature classes) into one feature class in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I clipped two shapefiles and created 2 clips but when adding the legend it adds all the same data in two clips but I want to add only one feature into the legend.

Is there any way to do it or can I merge two feature classes into one?

Comment: Clip wont merge them, try [Merge tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/merge.htm)

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to GIS SE! Please make sure you take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and become familiar with the format we follow here. A good question should be clear and direct, and give plenty of information to other users. I would suggest editing your question to clear up a few things: 1) The title of your question suggests you're just interested in merging vector layers, but your question text suggests the issue has more to do with the legend. 2) Can you elaborate on what you've already tried? This site should not be where you start your research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the ArcGIS toolbox, go to Data Management --> General --> Merge. For the inputs, select your two previously clipped shapefiles, and they will merge as one layer. This merged layer will appear on the legend. Make sure you remove the two clipped files from the legend to avoid overlap.